# Typescript parameters depending on each other

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

I do not understand the error I am getting below

Here is a minimal reproducible example, with the error message

```js
type LeftChild = {
    element: 0
}

type RightChild = {
    element: 1
}

type Left = {
    child: LeftChild
}

type Right = {
    child: RightChild
}

interface Typings {
    "left": {
        parent: Left
        child: LeftChild
    }
    "right": {
        parent: Right
        child: RightChild
    }
}

function foo<T extends keyof Typings>(parents: Typings[T]["parent"][], child: Typings[T]["child"]) {
    // Works
    parents[0].child = child

    // Doesn't work
    parents.push({ child })
    /*           ^^^^^^^^^
                Argument of type '{ child: Typings[T]["child"]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Typings[T]["member"]'.
                Type '{ child: Typings[T]["child"]; }' is not assignable to type 'Left | Right'.
                    Type '{ child: Typings[T]["child"]; }' is not assignable to type 'Right'.
                    Types of property 'child' are incompatible.
                        Type 'Typings[T]["child"]' is not assignable to type 'RightChild'.ts(2345)
    */
}
```

When copy-pasting the implementation for both types, it works fine

```js
function fooLeft(parents: Left[], child: LeftChild) {
    parents[0].child = child
    parents.push({ child })
}
function fooRight(parents: Right[], child: RightChild) {
    parents[0].child = child
    parents.push({ child })
}
```

What would be a proper type for my function? I'm trying to use generics to have the function operate on several types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot going on here; the short answer is that the compiler really isn't equipped to verify type safety in the face of *correlated* union typed expressions.  Consider this code:

```
declare const [a, b]: ["T", "X"] | ["U", "Y"]; // okay
const oops: ["T", "X"] | ["U", "Y"] = [a, b]; // error!
```

Here the variables `a` and `b` are correlated: if `a` is `"T"` then `b` must be `"X"`.  Otherwise `a` is `"U"` and `b` is `"Y"`.  The compiler sees `a` as type `"T" | "U"` and `b` as type `"X" | "Y"`, which are both true.  But by doing this it has failed to keep track of the correlation between them.  And so `[a, b]` is considered to be of type `["T", "X"] | ["T', "Y"] | ["U", "X"] | ["U", "Y"]`.  And you get errors.

---

This is what's happening to you, more or less.  I can rewrite your code into a non-generic version like this:

```
function fooEither(parents: Left[] | Right[], child: LeftChild | RightChild) {
  parents[0].child = child; // no error, but unsafe!
  parents.push({ child }) // error
}
fooEither([{ child: { element: 0 } }], { element: 1 }); // no error at compile time
```

Here you can see that the compiler is happy with `parents[0].child = child`, which it shouldn't be... and rightly unhappy about `parents.push({ child })`.  There's nothing that restricts `parents` and `child` to be properly correlated.

Why does `parents[0].child = child` work?  Well, the compiler largely does allow unsound property writes.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33911](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33911) for example, along with discussion around why they've decided to keep it that way.

I could try to rewrite the above code to enforce the correlation at the call site, but the compiler still can't see it inside the implementation:

```
function fooSpread(...[parents, child]: [Left[], LeftChild] | [Right[], RightChild]) {
  parents[0].child = child; // same no error
  parents.push({ child }) // same error
}
fooSpread([{ child: { element: 0 } }], { element: 1 }); // not allowed now, that's good
```

Without some way for the compiler to maintain correlations among union types, there's not much to be done here.

---

The two workarounds I've seen here is to duplicate code (much like `fooLeft()` and `fooRight()`) or to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to just silence the compiler:

```
function fooAssert<T extends keyof Typings>(parents: Typings[T]["parent"][], child: Typings[T]["child"]) {
  parents[0].child = child
  parents.push({ child } as Typings[T]["parent"]); // no error now
}
```

This compiles but only because *you* have taken the responsibility of telling *the compiler* that what you are doing is safe, not the other way around.  And it's dangerous because assertions make it more likely that you have done something unsafe without realizing it:

```
fooAssert([{ child: { element: 0 } }], { element: 1 }); // look ma no error
// fooAssert<"left"|"right">(...);
```

Oops, what happened?  Well, your call signature is generic in `T` but there is no parameter of type `T` passed in.  The compiler fails to infer anything for `T` and instead just widens it to its constraint, which is `"left" | "right"`.  And thus the call signature of `foo()` and `fooAssert()` is the same unsafe one as in `fooEither()`.  In this case if I were you I might fall back to something like `fooSpread()` which at least is safe to call.

---

The issue of correlated values  has come up often enough that I've filed an issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), suggesting that it would be nice to have something better than duplication or assertion here.  Alas, nothing obvious is forthcoming.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhBmwDCALAlgGwCZQLxQG8BYAKCiggwgFsIA7YALigAZSBfU00SKAJTQBzFMnTY8hUuUo16TKAEYOXEj2hxEE4mSgBjMVmYbRmLMpLdw0AcOBapeg8xsjUp86TQMIAJ3gBDXWgAFXAvQQBnSR0AIipEGOZtcnIwfx85IwRgB3J9UyzEN2wHTlifIRFE6JSoNIyGZ0qcnTynfmbisx0yspUsCF0MdOhdAHs6CLsAbX8AGigAIwBdZmmY4JiFmIANGOWoAB8odYBVLagYgE19gG4oAHoHqDGAa38QUnHJuzGxsAiaw2F12+yOJxi522NwO+FmCxW9yeFB8PjGPgAhCp4ABXOi6YBoCZQeB-ACiaGAKF8AAp6nJAbBstMDscXMAWQt8thCiZxGzOgYAJQ1OojBgRaYsZYAOm5OHw8qRzzoYxRaJ8CJxdjxEX88AgWJ09IlMrAOIiKBpBEcpig7BFyN8GvMpLGFKptOmNvlSQoVFojVY9vtywWNpkgfkCntQuVUFV6vRKlIuPxhOJboAymAMv4sDSZUXpibgBEuQZVidjJymUVK+Dpuza+yussRckxQ0y1LZfKJErHs89bQE2rncnjeKy2aLVafQZY0OoCPoBOfBwoKm-jm8wXvbaeYR-bIgywQ+ww8fI5lFLH46q7P4MBgxgB3CA4VVvo3YvEEok6BJP4AEEIgiXxgAAHmCCgAA9gHoLAoleCAQDGeAoFCMBwgiAA+Olp0ZbDcOmYJlnWUt9lrX0sLCOhIjIiiYnlfYOwcUtJWlOVF0VAwOKI2dLWtQ8cHYKB-CiEiGMlcjKOnNiH3HVF0THN8PBIN0wIgnxgBpA9aIjANb3PcTL3DE8o2YGMHXjV83igah-DHJMNxIZEtPAyCoLibIYkOGIKlsGICKLGU4z-dNAOAsZjEI7tGRrK9aOMLp2KnBLex4u0+PcDKGSE+dRNjDS0wAzM-nZeKGSaWwaPaVthVFTisv7XKSny01zWEhc7QdDSgA)