# TypeScript nested generic and conditional types assign error

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, conditional-types

Code example ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshCGBnArgJwgWwgO2FAvFAOQA2OA5sABZFQA+xGSitDRwAllq8QG4D2JZNwDcAKFCRYCFOiy4Aqtg7BEAGQrUCjDDyIBjXfWIATI213jJ0OEjSYcwJSsQxm2ouT0BrL1fA2MvbyTsqqACpc0IRELMZE5sQ0-lK2sg6KYYgAaoLC0cQkehgAzETiEgHSdnKOzqoAPDAAogCCAMoKAErNLQBy4VAQAB7AOCaI1ekhAHwEYlCwbZ09-YMjY9gThZo0UAD8U8F1WRrYlFQLUABcSx3dvc0DQ6PjkwnMtIdpx5kubohEFdbi17qsnutXlt3pxuAcjrU-hEosC7itHs8Nm8+Hk4d8gojQi5ckIsKjsBBeBBUBVrFAAML8bBU1CIDhMxkQABmXI4+g4jkmhAA3lcANqg9FrKAcbAIjLAAC6ty6EH0-FQJiaBIV9UQTWWDzWMwANFBsMIAEbUmZiAC+FXV2EQeCdLLZHP43N5-MFt0ZzOpHuwnJ5fIFuCFUFFizI52otxjiygGAwtwADAA6dPpgCMJqui0MGez+cLUDMJbLyZTt1zVztBcWTEBifL5BLOeryd8dYbTagsIgbZriDrA+btwAbOmJ1AqLcSjP+1cBKTh9HyyQ6znZ+XSn3Fnb7RUuchsPpOEyoG7qcADWCMZDNtsfoSZgAKK5YGoKkGG8EBgHXh4CEDcLQwa1UAHLlUH4NN5RCPUHylCFTSuYB+BBHUkKyFCjTQgcwHQflg32W4IKgsQAEoKKtalN1jCA8HQFASDwQgQLA8RFg4LkoA-WD4KgABCfBCEw6jGOTJ0XRvL0w19SMVTVDUtTfXU8MlAiBlNc16NQOZCFvVl2RDBSfQjVQxR-aZHEVEQoAAeicqAkCgVV1U1bVf1wlx8MA8I9Mom0eOTVjkHY7QIqigAqeTvXDQUxSEjBFWchLFKsxAxUwhyGzEK50GANA5WItUOGDAhxKgc8TG5WUIBMeEYrwW44Lq8J+AABRIyqzI-VqzXK0izOo8RjzEM8LyvOUOq2Lreoq4MPy45BwIM4a+qqwh01o-TIIYpNZLwDBIs4MASAFVBtFzdMoFi+KRv6pkwuK0rYHgahM3mkxVtA9aHpTc6OEu66pNcs72NBq7qQmoA)):

```js
type Measurement = 'length' | 'mass' | 'time' | 'volume';
type MeasurementUnitsLength = 'mm' | 'cm' | 'dm' | 'm';
type MeasurementUnitsMass = 'g' | 'kg';
type MeasurementUnitsTime = 's' | 'm' | 'h';
type MeasurementUnitsVolume = 'l' | 'm3';

type MeasurementUnits<MEASUREMENT extends Measurement> =
  MEASUREMENT extends 'length' ? MeasurementUnitsLength
  : MEASUREMENT extends 'mass' ? MeasurementUnitsMass
  : MEASUREMENT extends 'time' ? MeasurementUnitsTime
  : MEASUREMENT extends 'volume' ? MeasurementUnitsVolume
  : never;

type ConversionCoefficients = {
  [MEASUREMENT in Measurement]: Record<MeasurementUnits<MEASUREMENT>, number>
};

const conversionCoefficients: ConversionCoefficients = {
  length: {
    mm: 0.001,
    cm: 0.01,
    dm: 0.1,
    m: 1
  },
  mass: {
    g: 0.001,
    kg: 1
  },
  time: {
    s: 1,
    m: 60,
    h: 360
  },
  volume: {
    l: 1000,
    m3: 1
  }
};

function convert<MEASUREMENT extends Measurement>(
  measurement: MEASUREMENT,
  value: number,
  from: MeasurementUnits<MEASUREMENT>,
  to: MeasurementUnits<MEASUREMENT>,
  precision?: number
): number {
  let result = value;
  if (from !== to) {
    const coefficients: Record<MeasurementUnits<MEASUREMENT>, number> =
      conversionCoefficients[measurement]; // <---- Error is here
    result = result * coefficients[from] / coefficients[to];
  }

  return precision === undefined ? result : roundToPrecision(result, precision);
}

function roundToPrecision(value: number, precision = 0): number {
  const multiplier = 10 ** precision;
  return Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier;
}
```

**Error:**

TS2322: Type 'ConversionCoefficients[MEASUREMENT]' is not assignable to type 'Record<MeasurementUnits, number>'.   Type 'Record<MeasurementUnitsLength, number> | Record<MeasurementUnitsMass, number> | Record<MeasurementUnitsTime, number> | Record<...>' is not assignable to type 'Record<MeasurementUnits, number>'.     Type 'Record<MeasurementUnitsLength, number>' is not assignable to type 'Record<MeasurementUnits, number>'.

**Question:**

Why doesn't TS v4.2.3 infer type of `conversionCoefficients[measurement]` as `Record<MeasurementUnits<MEASUREMENT>, number>`? Why does it think that `conversionCoefficients[measurement]` type is a union?

Comment: This is going to be another instance of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62959293/typescript-parameters-depending-on-each-other.

Comment: As in the answers to the questions linked above, the compiler is technically correct to complain, since callers could always do this: `convert(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "mass" : "length", 1, "g", "cm");` as in [this code](https://tsplay.dev/w184lW).  Even if you can eliminate such possibilities, the compiler will not be able to perform the higher order analysis necessary to follow the generic correlations involved.  It's best to just use a type assertion as you're doing, at least for now.

Comment: Thank you @jcalz for the explanation. Now I understand how the compiler works. I just add explicit typecasting `conversionCoefficients[measurement] as Record<MeasurementUnits<MEASUREMENT>, number>` to avoid compilation error.